# Sort a Dictionary where the keys are date strings

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Dictionary. Each key is a date in the format of "dd-mm-yyyy"". The values are arrays of objects. I would like to sort the dictionary by date so that when I display each date as a section in a table view they are in chronological order.

```
  let sortedDict = self?.entriesDict.sorted(by: { $0.key > $1.key })
```

I think the above could possibly work if I reversed the date format however it is not returning a swift Dictionary (I think it is returning an NSDictionary).

Comment: I think you should actually uses Date types as the type of key for your dictionary, not strings.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Definitely. Previously we displayed all the data in a table with 1 section and sorted by a Unix timestamp each object has. I'm currently trying to segment the table into daily sections which has led to this temporary solution. I do need to reevaluate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Dictionary` is an unsorted collection by definition (an `NSDictionary` too). If you call `sorted` on a `Dictionary`, the return value will be of type `Array<(Key,Value)>`, an array of the key-value pairs in your dictionary represented as tuples.

To achieve your goals and use a `Dictionary` as a `UITableViewDataSource`, what you should do is keep a sorted array of your dictionary keys and in your data source methods, retrieve the correct key from that sorted array, then use the key to retrieve the value from the original dictionary.

I'd also suggest storing the dictionary keys as `Date` objects rather than date strings.

Without more context in your question, this is roughly what you should do:

```
let sortedKeys = entriesDict.keys.sorted()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedKeys.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellId", for: indexPath)
    let entryKey = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = entriesDict[entryKey]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow I always forget Dictionaries are unordered. My code definitely needs improved (using Date instead of a date string for example) but your advice helped me with a temporary solution. I get an array of the keys, sort those, and then use that array when fetching data for the table:                       var s = Array(entriesDict.keys)
s = s.sorted { $0 < $1 }